# Problems regarding PrimeFaces partial process

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, listener

In my application, I have this managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mrBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {


    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")
    private Long   commentableID;
    private String comment;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("INIT " + commentableID);
    }

    public void postComment() {
        System.out.println("POST COMMENT " + commentableID);
    }

    public void like(boolean like) {
        System.out.println("LIKE " + commentableID);
    }

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

**PROBLEM 1:**

On the page for viewing articles, I have the following box for commenting.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <p:inputTextarea id="comment" value="#{mrBean.comment}" />

    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.postComment}" value="Post">
        <f:param name="id"  value="#{viewCommentable.commentableID}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Everything works fine with the above code. However, since the `postComment()` function only requires the `comment` property, I tried to put in `process='comment'` into the above `p:commandButton`. At this point, whenever I click the `Post` button, I always see `INIT [commentableID]` on the console. However, I never see `POST COMMENT [commentableID]`. In other words, the listener method `postComment()` was never called even though the bean was created correctly.

**PROBLEM 2:**

On the same page, I have the following toggle buttons for liking/disliking an article.

```
<h:inputHidden id="commentableID" value="#{mrBean.commentableID}" />

<p:selectBooleanButton id="like" value="#{viewCommentable.commentable.liked}" onLabel="Liked" offLabel="Like" >
    <p:ajax process="like dislike commentableID" listener="#{mrBean.like(viewCommentable.commentable.liked)}" />
</p:selectBooleanButton>

<p:selectBooleanButton id="dislike" value="#{viewCommentable.commentable.disliked}" onLabel="Liked" offLabel="Like" >
    <p:ajax process="like dislike commentableID" listener="#{mrBean.dislike(viewCommentable.commentable.disliked)}" />
</p:selectBooleanButton>
```

These buttons are working fine. However, what I observed is quite weird. When I click the Like button, on the console I saw these lines:

```
INIT null
LIKE [commentableID]
```

Somehow, the property `commentableID` was not available in the `init()` function but it was later on in the `like()` function.

I'd be very grateful if you could give me an explanation for the above 2 problems.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally realised that I didn't use the `process` attribute correctly. In order to process partially, in a `<p:commandButton>`, I need the ids of the components that I want to process **as well as a `@this`** to process the button itself. Besides, another problem is that I didn't use the correct syntax for `process` attribute. The ids should be separated by a `comma` not a `space`. The following snippet should work:

```
<p:commandButton process="@this, comment" actionListener="#{mrBean.postComment}" value="Post">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{viewCommentable.commentableID}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:selectBooleanButton id="like" value="#{viewCommentable.commentable.liked}" onLabel="Liked" offLabel="Like" >
    <p:ajax process="like, dislike, commentableID" listener="#{mrBean.like(viewCommentable.commentable.liked)}" />
</p:selectBooleanButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add process and update attributes in your p:commandButton likes this,

```
     <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <p:inputTextarea id="comment" value="#{mrBean.comment}" />

        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.postComment}" value="Post" process="@this" update="grid">
          <f:param name="id"  value="#{viewCommentable.commentableID}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

But process attribute has many keywords such as @this, @form, @all ,etc. Show details in [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf)